# Is there a visual way to interact with an Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: transactions, remix, contract-deployment

I would like to interact with a smart contract deployed on a particular Ethereum TestNet using an address different from the one I used to create/deploy the contract which as far as I know is not possible in the Remix IDE which only allows you to connect to one MetaMask account at a time for the `Injected Web3` Environment.

Hence I would like to know if there's an alternative to the Remix `Deploy & Run Transactions` tab, which allows you to enter a contract address and automatically generates a list of the contracts `public` methods to interact with like in Remix, which I can then connect to using a specific MetaMask account and issue transactions to that smart contract. Also I have to interact with the contract on a TestNet as I'm interacting with a Chainlink Data Feed(via `AggregatorV3Interface`), so I don't think changing the Remix Deploy `Environment` to `Javascript VM` and using the dummy accounts available in that environment would be a feasible option.

[image: Remix Deploy & Run Transactions tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently you can interact with a smart contract deployed to an Ethereum TestNet from an address/account other than the one used to create/deploy the contract in Remix. All you have to do is click on the MetaMask extension and change the current/active account/address, doing so will automatically reflect and update the active account in Remix, and you can now interact with the given smart contract with the newly selected account.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, If you verify your contract you can call contracts's functions from scanner sites. for example https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ for rinkeby testnet. for every contract in scanner sites there is a tab named Contract and you can verify your contract there

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what's contract verification about?

Comment: For accessing contracts public methods

Comment: I see, thanks, how do I add my contract to the verified contracts list? also if I try executing one of the methods of the existing verified contracts I get the following error alert: Please connect to your Web3 provider!, how do I do that?

Comment: I came across a video tutorial that gives a decent walkthrough and explanation as to how contract verification works here: https://youtu.be/x1a5lrW-9fo